# How to do a Datatable filterby when redirecting the user to the filtered datatable

Tags: jquery, ajax, datatable

In my website I have an admin panel which redirect the user to a datatable.
I want the datatable to be filtered and displayed when the user is redirecting by clicking the link in the panel which gives the filtering option. 
I tried some methods but has given me no results.

The link on the admin panel:

```
<a href="listings/action=filterByState&status=DRAFT" class="small-box-footer">
    More info <i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-right"></i>
</a>
```

Datatable filterby option:

```
 <select id="status" name="status" class="form-control">
    <option value="ALL">All</option>
    <option value="<?php echo(ListingStatus::PUBLISHED); ?>">
      <?php echo(ListingStatus::PUBLISHED); ?></option>
    <option value="<?php echo(ListingStatus::DRAFT); ?>">
      <?php echo(ListingStatus::DRAFT); ?></option>
    <option value="<?php echo(ListingStatus::SCHEDULED); ?>">
      <?php echo(ListingStatus::SCHEDULED); ?></option>
 </select>
```

AJAX call for datatable filterby option:

```
function filterListingsByStatus(){
    $("#listingTbl").DataTable().destroy();

    var filterStatus = $("#status").val();

    $('#listingTbl').DataTable({
        "serverSide": true,
        "processing": true,
        "ordering": false,
        "searchDelay": 1000,
        "ajax": "listing-controller.php?action=filterByState&status="+filterStatus,
        "columns": [
            {"data": "id", "visible": false},
            {"data": "title"},
            {"data": "categories"},
            {"data": "tags"},
            {"data": "status"},
            {"data": "ext_ref_id"},
            {
                mRender: function (data, type, row) {
                    var linkEdit = '<a href="edit-listing.php?id=listingId">Edit</a>';
                    linkEdit = linkEdit.replace("listingId", row.id);

                    var linkDel = "<a href=\"#\" onclick=\"deleteListing(\'id\',\'title\')\">Delete</a>";
                    linkDel = linkDel.replace("id", row.id);
                    linkDel = linkDel.replace("title", row.title);

                    return linkEdit + " | " + linkDel;
                }
            }
        ],
        "columnDefs": [
            {"searchable": false, "targets": [0, 2, 3, 4, 5]}
        ],
        "language": {
            "searchPlaceholder": "by Title"
        },
        "pageLength": 25
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work in your case.

```
$('#status').change(function(){
    $('#listingTbl').DataTable().ajax.reload();
});
```

Don't write your datatable code in a defined function. 
Here is your code should look like. it should work.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){

        $('#status').change(function(){
            $('#listingTbl').DataTable().ajax.reload();
        });

       //var filterStatus = $("#status").val();

      $('#listingTbl').DataTable({
         "serverSide": true,
         "processing": true,
         "ordering": false,
         "searchDelay": 1000,
         "ajax": "listing-controller.php?action=filterByState&status="+$("#status").val(),
         "columns": [
             {"data": "id", "visible": false},
             {"data": "title"},
             {"data": "categories"},
             {"data": "tags"},
             {"data": "status"},
             {"data": "ext_ref_id"},
             {
                mRender: function (data, type, row) {
                    var linkEdit = '<a href="edit-listing.php?
                           id=listingId">Edit</a>';
                    linkEdit = linkEdit.replace("listingId", row.id);

                    var linkDel = "<a href=\"#\" 
                    onclick=\"deleteListing(\'id\',\'title\')\">Delete</a>";
                     linkDel = linkDel.replace("id", row.id);
                    linkDel = linkDel.replace("title", row.title);

                       return linkEdit + " | " + linkDel;
                    }
                }
            ],
             "columnDefs": [
             {"searchable": false, "targets": [0, 2, 3, 4, 5]}
             ],
             "language": {
                "searchPlaceholder": "by Title"
             },
             "pageLength": 25
         });
     });
</script>
```

Comment: No the filtering already working on the datatable itself. I want when the user clicks the link on the panel, the datatable to be filtered and displayed.

Comment: Thanks for the respond. But what should I include in the link?
how to call to the function to filter the datatable from the front-end?

Comment: in every reload event `var filterStatus` value will be the selected option. if `var filterStatus` value dose not change in every reload than instead of using `var filterStatus` use  `$("#status").val()` directly in the ajax link.

`"ajax": "listing-controller.php?action=filterByState&status="+$("#status").val(),`